# Java Spring WebClient - send multiple http requests using requests one after another using HTTP2

Tags: spring-webclient, reactor-netty

Small question on how to send multiple requests using a Java Spring WebClient to a HTTP2 enabled server, leveraging HTTP2 as client please.

I have a Java List/Iterator of payloads I need to send one after another to a third party server. I am the client.

The third party server, which I have no control over, was first HTTP1 only.

Recently, they migrated to HTTP2, and they now fully support HTTP2.

When it was still HTTP1 enabled, I was using this code: (note the `http1Client` vs `http2Client`), here is what I am trying

```
 private static Iterator<String> sendRequestsLeverageHttpTwo(Iterator<String> requestsPayload) {
        List<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
        while (requestsPayload.hasNext()) {
            String requestPayload = requestsPayload.next();

            HttpClient http1Client = HttpClient.create().wiretap(true).protocol(HttpProtocol.HTTP11); // was using this when the server only supports HTTP1
            HttpClient http2Client = HttpClient.create().wiretap(true).protocol(HttpProtocol.H2); //now using this as the server supports HTTP2

            final WebClient webClient =
                    WebClient.create().mutate().defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(http2Client)).build(); //replace http1Client -> http2Client

            final String response = webClient.post().uri("http://the-http-two-enabled-server/api").body(BodyInserters.fromValue(requestPayload)).retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();
            if (!"".equals(response)) {
                linkedList.add("OK");
            }
        }
        return linkedList.iterator();
    }
```

The third party server is now supporting HTTP2, I swapped for the `http2Client`.

Things "work", the third party server told me they are able to see in their access logs, all my requests are now HTTP2, happy.

The problem is, I realize on the client side, me, I am using HTTP2 here like HTTP1!

Meaning, candid as I am, I just swapped the HttpClient, and don't think I am leveraging any of HTTP2 technology.

Looking at this code, I am really just doing the same as before, but just with `HttpProtocol.H2`. I do not think this is fully leveraging the step up from HTTP1 to HTTP2, please correct me if I am wrong.

My question is, how to properly fully leverage the step up HTTP2 while sending this collection of payloads to the HTTP2 enabled back end please?

Thank you

Comment: It's not required to specify protocol explicitly. The protocol is determined/negotiated per connection automatically by `WebClient` and underlining Netty client. Check [HTTP 2 support](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/HTTP-2-support) for more details.

Comment: I think this is a great question (because I also have the same question lol). Spring says it supports HTTP2. But the main benefit of HTTP2 is multiplexing via single connection. But here webclient still creates more connection. So I do not understand what they mean by spring supports HTTP2 here.

Comment: Totally agree @RamPrakash